# Get Child value in LINQ to Entity

Tags: c#, linq, entity

I have LINQ Query which return result in below format

```
 -- Parent1
 ----Childs
 ------key - aa
 ------value - new
 ----Childs
 ------key - bb
 ------value - old
 -- Parent2
 ----Childs
 ------key - cc
 ------value - test
 ----Childs
 ------key - dd
 ------value - tesst
```

I want to fetch the child value in **one** line using Linq. currently I can get the value but in two line of code which i don't like it

```
 var firstPoint = SeriesList.Select(i => i.Childs.Where(j => j.key == "aa"))
                            .FirstOrDefault();
 decimal index = firstPoint.Select(d => d.Value)
                           .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Since you're using `FirstOrDefault()`, if you *don't* do it as two lines and do a null check between them, you run the risk of getting a `NullReferenceException`.  If you want an exception to be thrown in that case, use `First()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
decimal index = SeriesList.Select(i => i.Childs.Where(j => j.key == "aa"))
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var firstPoint = SeriesList.Select(i => i.Childs.Where(j => j.key == "aa")).FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Comment: I Tried got the below error 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SeriesList>' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SeriesList>'

Comment: What about `var firstPoint = SeriesList.Select(i => i.Childs.Where(j => j.key == "aa")).FirstOrDefault().Select(d => d.Value).FirstOrDefault();`?

Answer (score 1):

```
decimal index = SeriesList.SelectMany(p => p.Childs)
                          .FirstOrDefault(c => c.key == "aa").Value;
```

But keep in mind, that child with provided key should exist in list, otherwise you will get an exception. I think better to find child first, and then if child exist, get its value:

```
Childs child = SeriesList.SelectMany(p => p.Childs)
                          .FirstOrDefault(c => c.key == "aa");
if (child != null)
    index = child.Value;
```

Comment: This is functionally different than the OPs code.  His gets the first parent and then the first child meeting X condition, you get all of the children from each parent and then the first child meeting a condition.  It may be what he wants, but it also might not be.

Comment: @Servy agree, there is one way to find out what OP needs :) Actually data structure is not clear for me - is there several Childs elements in each parent, or not

Comment: His example lists two children for each parent, so yes.

Comment: @Servy there are two Childs elements, not single collection named Childs, which has several Child elements. Anyway, you found out what OP needs, thus +1 from me :)